# Multiple JTables - Cell selection between tables

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Ive got a weird issue, hoping someone can help. Ive got a bunch of different tables, added to panels, added to a common scrollpane. When a user clicks on a cell, it highlights it to show the cell selection, just the standard highlight, this is fine. I set:

```
tables[nr].setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

When you click on a different table though the original table keeps its selection highlight. Only if you click on a different cell within the same table does the selection change.

Is there any way to only have 1 cell selected at a time for this setup I have here? So only 1 cell selected throughout all the applicable tables

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Do you want cells of the table to be selected instead of row?

Comment: Okay sorry i figured something out. What i did was to add a focus listener to each one of my tables and when the focus is lost i call clearSelection() on the table

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for a **quick solution** to the problem, here is the **code** for deselecting all the selected rows and columns of the table, once the table looses focus.

```
jtable.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        clearSelection();
    }
});
```

Simply **add this focus listener to each of your tables** and their selected rows and columns will be deselected, once you select the records in a different table.